# How to change category as categories in layered Navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I want to change the label of Category  text at the layered navigation.Want to change category Label  text `Category to  Categories` here in the layered navigation but I cannot find where can I do this please help me.

Kindly  see the  screen shot

[image]

Comment: go to this file `theme/template/catalog/navigation/topnavigation.phtml` this displays the category navigation bar.

Comment: Ofcourse i know categories are got from that page but that is not the issue I wanna change CATEGORY as CATEGORIES in tha file you mentioned the menu is get dynamically.

Comment: you could also simply do `<?php echo str_replace('Category', 'Categories', $this->__($_filter->getName())) ?>` in `app/design/frontend/package/theme/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  need change at getName function at class `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category`

```
 public function getName()
    {
        return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Category');
```

to

```
 public function getName()
    {
        return Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Categories ');
    }
```

For proper way you need to  rewrite this model class.To Over write core model class refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22144272/how-to-override-magento-core-model-model-class-file-direct-under-app-code-core).

Comment: can you please tell me where can i change products visblity in rows like in all products view page for row I'm having 3 products i want 4 products to be in one row how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

1. Please create file `left.phtml` (Copy from the base folder file path `[base_template]/catalog/navigation/left.phtml`)

as in your current theme template

`[current_theme_template]/catalog/navigation/left.phtml`

and change the text `echo $this->__('Category')` line number 44 as `Categories`

2. You can also change in CSV file `app/locale/en_US/Mage_Catalog.csv` line number 168 as categories. But this will change `Category` as `Categories` in all places.